# While using setcontentview in a BottomsheetDialog an error like "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" occurs

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a BottomsheetDialog in my fragment. But when I try to call `bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view)` an error like

> none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
>   setContentView(View!) defined in android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog
>   setContentView(Int) defined in android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog

It's working perfectly when I'm implementing it with Java code. But while trying to implement the same with Kotlin this error occurs,

providing the code I have tried out with Kotlin,

```
private fun showRenewDialog(renewModel: RenewModel?) {

    if (bottomSheetDialog == null) bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(activity)
    val view:View? = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.renewal_dialog, null, false)
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view)

}
```

The same code with Java

```
if (bottomSheetDialog == null) bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_dialog, null, false);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your Kotlin Code you don't need to pass paramas just go with this one,

```
 fun openBottomSheetDialog() {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this@YOUR_CLASS_NAME) // if it is a activity than @DetailActivity
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.book_dialog)
        dialog.show()
    }
```